# ref() ou child() ao ler dados firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, realtime-database

Qual a diferença entre `ref()` e `child()` no firebase? Quando devo usar um ou outro? Tem alguma diferença de performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os 2 são métodos de classes diferentes, mas retornam a mesma coisa: uma [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference). O `ref()` é da classe [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database) e o `child()` da classe [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference).

Vamos ver o funcionamento destes métodos:

1. `ref()` - retorna uma referência para o nó da base de dados passado como parâmetro. Se não tiver nenhum parâmetro especificado, ele retorna a referência para o nó raíz da base de dados.
2. `child()` - retorna também uma referência para um nó da base de dados. Mas a diferença é que ele serve para aceder à sub-nós dentro de uma Reference.

Tendo em conta que o `child()` é da classe Reference e devolve também um objecto Reference, você pode utilizar childs encadeados da seguinte forma:

```
ref.child("users").child("uid1").child("nome")
```

Mas o mesmo não acontece com o `ref()`. **Não é possível** fazer `ref.ref("users").ref("uid1").ref("nome")`.

---

É possível também aceder à sub-nós utilizando o `ref()`:

```
ref = database.ref("users/uid1/nome");
```

E utilizando o `child()`:

```
ref = database.ref().child("users/uid1/nome");
//ou até
ref = database.ref("users").child("uid1/nome")
```

**Resumindo:** No fim, os 2 métodos retornam a mesma coisa e não têm nenhuma diferença em termos de performance. Utilize o método que te deixa mais confortável.

Comment: Tem diferença de performance `chlid('a/b')` e `child('a').child('b')`?

Comment: Não há nada documentado pelo Firebase. Mas se tiver alguma diferença será mínima e desprezível.